# Changing target to x64 breaks the FLTK build in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, fltk

I'm trying to build the FLTK version 1.3.4 which you can find from http://www.fltk.org/software.php in Visual Studio 2017.

1. I unzip everything, navigate to the ide/VisualC2010/ folder, and open the **fltk.sln** file in Visual Studio 2017.
2. Visual Studio asks if I would like to upgrade project targets to the latest Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 toolset. The upgrade options are **Windows SDK Version: 10.0.16299.0** and **Platform Toolset: Upgrade to v141**. I press OK.
3. At this point if I do **Build->Build Solution (Ctrl Shift B)**, everything works. However I noticed that the target is Win32 and I would like to also compile the library so I can link against x64 programs.
4. I go to **Build->Configuration Manager** and then in the **Active Solution Platform->New...** and **Type or select new platform: x64** and **Copy settings from: Win32** and **Create new project platforms [checked]** and then I press OK. This takes a while to complete.
5. Repeating step 3 no longer succeeds, with many projects failing with *fatal error c1041: cannot open program database ...*

I am pretty much a beginner at Visual Studio and I don't really understand what I'm doing. Can someone clue me in on what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by going to **Tools -> Options** and then **Build and Run** and then I changed **maximum number of parallel project builds** from 4 to 1.